# Enhanced for loop problem

Tags: java, foreach

Why is my enhanced loop not working?

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
          v.add("one"); 
          v.add("two");
          v.add("three");
          for(String str : v){
              System.out.println(v);
          }
```

Comment: Word of advice for the future, Antony. The best "What's going wrong?" questions consist of code along with expected and actual behaviour (such as "I expected 'one two three' but instead got 'one two three one two three one two three'"). That'll make it a lot easier to nut out the problem (despite the fact that Carlos figured it out anyway).

Comment: Unrelated, I curious why you chose to use Vector instead of ArrayList? Is there some tutorial material out there that advocates Vector?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with you code is that in the for statement instead of this:

```
          for(String str : v){
              System.out.println(v);
          }
```

you should have this:

```
          for(String str : v){
              System.out.println(str);
          }
```

making the final code like this:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
          v.add("one"); 
          v.add("two");
          v.add("three");
          for(String str : v){
              System.out.println(str);
          }
```

In simple terms you are giving the value of `v` to a string called `str`, then you print it using `System.out.println(...)` and this loop will continue until there are no more items left from `v` to print.

Hope it helps.